# Python suprocess.run() for Windows

Tags: python, subprocess

I create a png file and view it on macOS with

```
[...]
image.save("mandel.png", "PNG")
p = subprocess.run(["open", "mandel.png"], capture_output=True)
print(p.stdout.decode(),p.stderr.decode())
```

But what have I to choose for windows? "open" doesn't work on Win10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[...]
image.save("mandel.png", "PNG")
p = subprocess.run(["start", "mandel.png"], capture_output=True)
print(p.stdout.decode(),p.stderr.decode())
```

You can use the `start` command in windows.

***Reference:***

http://www.frankworsley.com/blog/2007/9/24/open-a-file-in-the-default-application-using-the-windows-command-line-without-jdic

Comment: Doesn't work for Win10 (in a virtual box on macOS). I had to use `os.startfile("mandel.png", 'open')`